# How do I organise my page.[slugURL].php files into sub directories in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In the interest of keeping my WordPress theme files organised, I am looking to create the following structure on my server:

/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/ and then the following folders within ...

- theme name folder

  - bootstrap
  - content
  - css
  - js
  - templates
  - pages

I have managed to get my folders working correctly, with the exception of the **'pages' folder**.  I want my **'pages' folder** to house all the **'pages-[slugURL].php' files**.  When placed in the **'/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/theme-name'** directory, the files are recognised and displayed accordingly in the browser.  Unfortunately, when placed in the **'pages' folder**, they are not recognised.

Is there a work around for this?  I realise that I could simply leave the affected files where they are, but as this is my first attempt at making a WordPress theme from scratch, I would like everything as organised as possible, as to reduce any confusions in the future.  Furthermore, I believe this would be just good practice anyway.

It would be appreciated, if anyone could let me know if there is a workaround on this.

Regards

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way around that. You can create a file called page in default directory with this content:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    get_template_part( 'pages/page', $post->post_name );
?>
```

And then just place all your `page-[slugURL].php` files into the pages directory.

But I am not suggesting to do this, because it is not following standard WordPress Template Hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress template hierarchy does not allow you to this easily. You can read all details on the template hierarchy in WordPress [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

If you want a special folder for your pages, you need to use `template_redirect` action to help WordPress to find the template you choose for those pages. All details  [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).

Hope it helps!